# Flutter devtools search widget tree details?

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

I am trying to search for something in the Widget Details Tree of the devtools inspector but it doesn't seem like I can. There is a search function in the Widget Tree in the devtools but not the Widget Details Tree. Is it possible to search the Widget Details Tree?

[image]